# how to stream hololens video to ios?

Tags: ios, hololens

Here i have tried with the following code, but the video is not displaying in the player. I have even tried with the OBS but cannot able to stream to ios. Can any one help me in this?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://username:password@ip_address/api/holographic/stream/live_high.mp4?holo=true&pv=true&mic=true&loopback=true"];
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,500,300);
controller.player = _player;
[_player play];
```